# Sample CakePHP Application

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp

I'm looking for a basic CakePHP application I can use as base for a new project and future ones as well. What I need is basic functionality such as users, user groups, login and register and forgot password. I have been doing some Googling and found a few tutorials and that but all don't seem to be what I'm after. I found BakeMe which seemed good, but had lots of errors and doesn't seem to have been updated.

Anyone know of some good ones? Or perhaps have their own skeleton they use for new projects that they would be happy to share. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the 'standard' blog tutorial: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1528/Blog
You could follow this up with the ACL tutorial and so tick most of your boxes: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1543/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application

I really recommend these two. They will introduce you to so many fundamental concepts of CakePHP that you'd be foolish to skip them. Anything built with CakePHP is extensible and the Cake Blog is no exception.

Comment: The problem with the second tutorial is that it wants to use Bake and I don't want to. So they don't have the source code for some of the files.

Comment: @Cameron yeah, I had exactly the same problem, I don't get bake. However, here's a great tutorial for the rest of us http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-cakephps-access-control-lists/

Comment: held me up on it for a while, but I'm glad I did in the end. I actually used Mark Story's blog posts http://mark-story.com/posts/view/auth-and-acl-an-end-to-end-tutorial-pt-1 but he wrote the tutorial anyway.